# Applying a wet rub/marinade after a dry rub for chicken?

Tags: chicken, marinade

I recently cooked some chicken with a dry "brine"/"rub" of Indian spices and salt to great results. It was crispy and moist.

My question is: is it worth it to apply a wet marinade after a dry "brine"?

My understanding is that a dry rub seasons meat from the inside, as the salt is pulled into the meat via osmosis when it draws water out. A marinade, by contrast, is a surface level treatment.

Combing the two, I could salt a piece of chicken (or other meat), and then apply a Chipotle marinade or a Teriyaki marinade, and then pan-fry. Does this result in the best of both worlds? Even if the internal salt is pulled out, hasn't it already denatured the proteins to lock the moisture in?

I also used dry rub and dry brine interchangeably since mine included salt. Is this okay?

Comment: I don't understand your question. A dry rub still flavors the surface, what do you see a marinade doing in addition?

Comment: Do you want crispy skin?  If so, I would avoid the wet marinade.

Comment: @moscafj That makes sense.